# How can I change field option in model automatically in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

How can I change model's field option in specific condition?
For example, I want to change option of `is_it_question` (editable) to `False` via `save` function.

```
class TypeFourChoice(models.Model):
    question_choice = models.ForeignKey(TypeFour)
    is_it_question = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, default=100, editable=False)
    word_or_words = models.CharField(default='', blank=False, max_length=20)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} : {}".format(self.question_choice, self.word_or_words)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None and self.is_it_question:
            self.number = TypeFourChoice.objects.filter(is_it_question=True).count() + 1
            ؟؟؟؟***self.is_it_question.editable = False***????
        super(TypeFourChoice, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for this statements

```
self._meta.get_field_by_name('is_it_question')[0].editable = False
```

but you have to pay attention to consequences of this action, read about on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847278/setting-django-unique-model-field-parameter-after-creation-of-model-objects-wi).

Comment: Thanks, it works good, but it change this option for then and after records! how can I say that Django do it just for some records? I mean for some it be editable and for else not!

Comment: @altruistic : Maybe it is better to add to your model an appropriate field for manage `non editable` question.